# OpenSearch - Can you run calculations on parameters in search template?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-template

Is it possible to run calculations on parameters inserted into your search function?

For example,

col_name_value = "10"  and i want to match on values of 100.

```
              "match": {
                "column_name": {
                  "query": "{{col_nam_value}} * 10"
                }
              }
            }
```

I've scanned the documentation and I can't see anything. I'm assuming you can't as it's a string but thought i'd double check.

Answer (score 0):

you were right: you cannot
(neither you can with Elasticsearch)

However, I'm not sure what client you're using, but that calculation seems fairly trivial to do with any client